# Magento 2.0 vs 2.1 - which is better to use right now?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am currently doing development on Magento 2.0.4 and i need to deploy my site in 1 month.

So the question is:

Is it better to keep using Magento 2.0 or should i move to 2.1.?
also Magento 2.1 has admin structure changes that I'll have to do as well, like admin tabs are removed from 2.1 etc.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Open questions and discussions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A - you'll get better
results at the Magento forums (http://community.magento.com) or
Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Answer (score 5):

You should always pursue the latest available stable release. Updating your site to 2.1 before it goes live will only make later upgrades easier, and you get a whole bunch of bugfixes in the process.

Whether you update to 2.1 or not, you *need* to update. There were major security vulnerabilities addressed in version 2.0.6. If you're running a version older (and 2.0.4 is older), you are liable to get hacked. See the release notes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.0.6CE.html

Answer (score 0):

2.1 branch is better. 2.0.x - does not contain improvements and fix of some issues

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not update it to Magento2.1 right now as you have less time, there might be some issues that may appear at your way. If you have time to update and fix all of them then better update else you should do it later. Magento 2.1 still have several issues. Which I found while using APi For example:- when we are trying to fetch the list of updated product(I modified price) via SOAP api using below url

> (Yourhost/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=2016-08-10%2012:45:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=gt&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-08-10%2012:52:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=leq)

then we are not getting updated product. Also there are some more new modification. For example by default guest access for API is set to No.

Comment: "For example by default guest access for API is set to No." There's a very good reason for that... it's a massive security/data-exposure risk to have enabled by default.

Comment: Yes, its really good. There are several other modification too but we need to review/test our code thoroughly if wanted to upgrade before any major release. Thus considering such things are important. :)